# application form

Tags: javascript

user must be able to insert name,address,gender,color and module....when user clicks the clear button,the form should be cleared, and when user clicks the Ok Button,the name and address should be displayed below the form..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
 function buttonOk()
{
 var but = document.getElementById("button");
 var txt=document.getElementById("name").value;
 document.getElementById("name").value=txt;
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
   <h2> Application Form <h2>

   <form>
   <table>
     <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td>
             <input type="text" name="name" size=30 value=" ">
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> Address</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="address" size=30 value=" ">
        </td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="M"> Male
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="F"> Female 
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Stream</td>
        <td>
            <select name="stream">
            <option value="0" selected>---Select color--</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            </select><br  /> 
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Modules</td>
         <td>
             <input type="checkbox" name="module" value="m1"> M1
             <input type="checkbox" name="module" value="m2"> M2
             <input type="checkbox" name="module" value="m3"> M3
             <input type="checkbox" name="module" value="m4"> M4 
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
           <input type="submit" name="butt" value="Clear">
           <input type="submit" name="button" value="OK">
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>

<hr size="2" noshade />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <input type="reset" value="reset">

Comment: What are you actually having problems with? What have you tried? Please make your question more specific. Read the FAQ for tips: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920817/application-form)

Answer (score 0):

set input type to reset for clear button

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
```

Answer (score 0):

This one might be helpful you

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eHaKIna/2/edit)

```
<td>
    <input type="reset" name="butt" value="Clear" />
</td>
```