# JAVASCRIPT-FORM

Tags: javascript

User must be able to insert name,address,gender,stream and module....when user clicks the clear button,the form should be cleared, and when user clicks the Ok Button,the name and address should be displayed below the form..

Problem: Clear button doesn't work properly.how can i correct it??

**Application.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ApplicationForm.js"></script>
 </head>


 <body>
<form id="frm1">
            <!-----Application Table ---->
<table cellpadding="8">
<tr>
                 <td>Name</td>
                 <td><input type="text" id="txtName" size=30 value=" "></td>
           </tr>

<tr>
                 <td> Address</td>
                 <td><input type="text" id="txtAdd" size=30 value=" "></td>
           </tr> 

<tr>
                 <td>Gender</td>
                 <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="M"> Male
                         <input type="radio" name="sex" value="F"> Female </td>
</tr>

<tr>
                  <td>Stream </td>
                  <td><select name="stream">
      <option id="0" value="0">---Select stream---</option>
      <option id="1" value="se">SE</option>
                  <option id="2" value="isbm">ISBM</option>
                  </select><br  /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
      <td>Modules</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="module" value="m1"> M1
                          <input type="checkbox" name="module" value="m2"> M2
              <input type="checkbox" name="module" value="m3"> M3
                          <input type="checkbox" name="module" value="m4"> M4 

</td>
</tr>

            <tr>
     <td><input type="button" name="submit" value="OK" onclick="clickOk()">
                         <input type="button" name="reset" value="Clear" 
                           onclick="formReset()"></td>
           </tr>



</table>
</form>
       <div id="display"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

**ApplicationForm.js**

```
function clickOk(){

  if(document.getElementById("txtName").value!=" "){

              if(document.getElementById("txtAdd").value!=" "){

                   var nam=document.getElementById("txtName").value;
                   var add=document.getElementById("txtAdd").value;

              document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="<hr>Hi 
             "+nam+"<br>Address: "+add;
                        }

              else 
                   alert("Please enter your Address");
              }

else 
         alert("Please enter your Name");
}


function formReset()
{
document.getElementById("frm1").reset();
}
```

Comment: Strange, the code looks ok... the first step should be looking for errors in the JavaScript console. And are you sure you need a "clear" button in the first place? What for? The only thing they've done for me over the past 15 years was occasionally  destroy my form input when I accidentally clicked on them.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">
```

is all that you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will display two fields in display area,In order to use reset function use `type=reset` in form input it will reset form fields

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset form" />
```

Script

```
function clickOk(){

  if(document.getElementById("txtName").value!=" "){

              if(document.getElementById("txtAdd").value!=" "){

                   var nam=document.getElementById("txtName").value;
                   var add=document.getElementById("txtAdd").value;

              document.getElementById("display").innerHTML='<hr>Hi ' 
             +nam+'<br>Address: '+add;
                        }

              else 
                   alert("Please enter your Address");
              }

else 
         alert("Please enter your Name");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XbE8R/1/)